# Query Results Show Fewer Rows Than Expected - Getting 27 Instead of 37 Rows

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue with a SQL query in my PHP application. I have a database with three tables: "post," "category," and "user." The "post" table contains 37 rows, and I want to retrieve data from it along with related information from the other two tables using a JOIN.

Here's the SQL query I am using:

```
SELECT title, post_date, first_name, last_name, category_name
FROM ((post p
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category = c.category_id)
INNER JOIN user u ON p.author = u.user_id)
ORDER BY post_id;
```

When I run this query, I expect to get all 37 rows as results. However, both in my local environment and on my production server, the query only returns 27 rows, as indicated by the message "Showing rows 0 - 26 (27 total, Query took 0.0017 seconds.)".

I ran a COUNT query to confirm the number of rows in the "post" table, and it returned the expected result:

```
SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM post;
```

```
COUNT(post_id)
37
```

Despite the COUNT query returning 37 rows, the SELECT query only retrieves 27 rows. Could there be any reasons for this discrepancy? Is there anything I might be overlooking in my code or database setup that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Not all posts have a category and/or author